# About String Data Types

Tags: vb.net, string, variables

This is my second post in as many hours, not sure if there is a limit on how many times we can post but I was just wondering if you could figure out why this piece of code is not working?

```
 Dim grading As String

    If score <= 5 Then
        grading = "Good Job!"
    ElseIf score < 15 > 5 Then
        grading = "Better Luck Next Time"

    End If


    MessageBox.Show("Your Brain Age is" & score & "." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & grading, "Brain Age")

End Sub
```

Basically what's happening is that when I use the variable grading in the messagebox, the following error comes up

> Warning    1   Variable 'grading' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

I'm sure there is a quick and easy solution.

I want to use a string in a messagebox but cannot get it to work - check code

Comment: `ElseIf score < 15 > 5 Then` is not valid syntax.  Is that a typo?  What was it supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your main question, the problem is that if none of the following conditions are met:

```
If score <= 5 Then
    grading = "Good Job!"
ElseIf score < 15 > 5 Then
    grading = "Better Luck Next Time"
End If
```

... then the `grading` variable remains unassigned, and the compiler appropriately thinks that you didn't intend to do this.

To fix this, either initialize the `grading` variable with an appropriate value:

```
Dim grading As String = "default value"
```

Or, add an `else` block to ensure that you always set something to `grading` before attempting to use it:

```
If score <= 5 Then
    grading = "Good Job!"
ElseIf score < 15 > 5 Then
    grading = "Better Luck Next Time"
Else
    grading = "default value"
End If
```

---

Also, you may want to revise the following:

```
ElseIf score < 15 > 5 Then
```

... it doesn't look right.  Did you mean this instead?

```
ElseIf score < 15 AndAlso score > 5 Then
```